# Send records using async or sync way

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented, interfaces, abstract-class

I have bunch of keys and values that I want to send to our messaging queue by packing them in one byte array. I will make one byte array of all the keys and values which should always be less than 50K and then send to our messaging queue.

**Packet class**:

```
public final class Packet implements Closeable {
  private static final int MAX_SIZE = 50000;
  private static final int HEADER_SIZE = 36;

  private final byte dataCenter;
  private final byte recordVersion;
  private final long address;
  private final long addressFrom;
  private final long addressOrigin;
  private final byte recordsPartition;
  private final byte replicated;
  private final ByteBuffer itemBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_SIZE);
  private int pendingItems = 0;

  public Packet(final RecordPartition recordPartition) {
    this.recordsPartition = (byte) recordPartition.getPartition();
    this.dataCenter = Utils.LOCATION.get().datacenter();
    this.recordVersion = 1;
    this.replicated = 0;
    final long packedAddress = new Data().packAddress();
    this.address = packedAddress;
    this.addressFrom = 0L;
    this.addressOrigin = packedAddress;
  }

  private void addHeader(final ByteBuffer buffer, final int items) {
    buffer.put(dataCenter).put(recordVersion).putInt(items).putInt(buffer.capacity())
        .putLong(address).putLong(addressFrom).putLong(addressOrigin).put(recordsPartition)
        .put(replicated);
  }

  private void sendData() {
    if (itemBuffer.position() == 0) {
      // no data to be sent
      return;
    }
    final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_SIZE);
    addHeader(buffer, pendingItems);
    buffer.put(itemBuffer);
    SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueAsync(address, buffer.array());
    // SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueAsync(address, buffer.array());
    // SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueSync(address, buffer.array());
    // SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueSync(address, buffer.array(), socket);
    itemBuffer.clear();
    pendingItems = 0;
  }

  public void addAndSendJunked(final byte[] key, final byte[] data) {
    if (key.length > 255) {
      return;
    }
    final byte keyLength = (byte) key.length;
    final byte dataLength = (byte) data.length;

    final int additionalSize = dataLength + keyLength + 1 + 1 + 8 + 2;
    final int newSize = itemBuffer.position() + additionalSize;
    if (newSize >= (MAX_SIZE - HEADER_SIZE)) {
      sendData();
    }
    if (additionalSize > (MAX_SIZE - HEADER_SIZE)) {
      throw new AppConfigurationException("Size of single item exceeds maximum size");
    }

    final ByteBuffer dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    final long timestamp = dataLength > 10 ? dataBuffer.getLong(2) : System.currentTimeMillis();
    // data layout
    itemBuffer.put((byte) 0).put(keyLength).put(key).putLong(timestamp).putShort(dataLength)
        .put(data);
    pendingItems++;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    if (pendingItems > 0) {
      sendData();
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the way I am sending data. As of now my design only permits to send data asynchronously by calling `sender.sendToQueueAsync` method in `sendData()` method.

```
  private void validateAndSend(final RecordPartition partition) {
    final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder> dataHolders = dataHoldersByPartition.get(partition);

    final Packet packet = new Packet(partition);

    DataHolder dataHolder;
    while ((dataHolder = dataHolders.poll()) != null) {
      packet.addAndSendJunked(dataHolder.getClientKey().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
          dataHolder.getProcessBytes());
    }
    packet.close();
  }
```

Now I need to extend my design so that I can send data in three different ways. It is upto user to decide which way he wants to send data to either "sync" or "async".

- I need to send data asynchronously by calling `sender.sendToQueueAsync` method.
- or I need to send data synchronously by calling `sender.sendToQueueSync` method.
- or I need to send data synchronously but on a particular socket by calling `sender.sendToQueueSync` method. In this case I need to pass `socket` variable somehow so that `sendData` knows about this variable.

**SendRecord class**:

```
public class SendRecord {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
  private final Cache<Long, PendingMessage> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(1000000)
      .concurrencyLevel(100).build();

  private static class Holder {
    private static final SendRecord INSTANCE = new SendRecord();
  }

  public static SendRecord getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private SendRecord() {
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        handleRetry();
      }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  private void handleRetry() {
    List<PendingMessage> messages = new ArrayList<>(cache.asMap().values());
    for (PendingMessage message : messages) {
      if (message.hasExpired()) {
        if (message.shouldRetry()) {
          message.markResent();
          doSendAsync(message);
        } else {
          cache.invalidate(message.getAddress());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // called by multiple threads concurrently
  public boolean sendToQueueAsync(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords) {
    PendingMessage m = new PendingMessage(address, encodedRecords, true);
    cache.put(address, m);
    return doSendAsync(m);
  }

  // called by above method and also by handleRetry method
  private boolean doSendAsync(final PendingMessage pendingMessage) {
    Optional<SocketHolder> liveSocket = SocketManager.getInstance().getNextSocket();
    ZMsg msg = new ZMsg();
    msg.add(pendingMessage.getEncodedRecords());
    try {
      // this returns instantly
      return msg.send(liveSocket.get().getSocket());
    } finally {
      msg.destroy();
    }
  }

  // called by send method below
  private boolean doSendAsync(final PendingMessage pendingMessage, final Socket socket) {
    ZMsg msg = new ZMsg();
    msg.add(pendingMessage.getEncodedRecords());
    try {
      // this returns instantly
      return msg.send(socket);
    } finally {
      msg.destroy();
    }
  }

  // called by multiple threads to send data synchronously without passing socket
  public boolean sendToQueueSync(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords) {
    PendingMessage m = new PendingMessage(address, encodedRecords, false);
    cache.put(address, m);
    try {
      if (doSendAsync(m)) {
        return m.waitForAck();
      }
      return false;
    } finally {
      cache.invalidate(address);
    }
  }

  // called by a threads to send data synchronously but with socket as the parameter
  public boolean sendToQueueSync(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords, final Socket socket) {
    PendingMessage m = new PendingMessage(address, encodedRecords, false);
    cache.put(address, m);
    try {
      if (doSendAsync(m, socket)) {
        return m.waitForAck();
      }
      return false;
    } finally {
      cache.invalidate(address);
    }
  }

  public void handleAckReceived(final long address) {
    PendingMessage record = cache.getIfPresent(address);
    if (record != null) {
      record.ackReceived();
      cache.invalidate(address);
    }
  }
}
```

Callers will only call either of below three methods:

- sendToQueueAsync by passing two parameters
- sendToQueueSync by passing two parameters
- sendToQueueSync by passing three parameters

How should I design my `Packet` and `SendRecord` class so that I can tell `Packet` class that this data needs to be send in either of above three ways to my messaging queue. It is upto user to decide which way he wants to send data to messaging queue. As of now the way my `Packet` class is structured, it can send data only in one way.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  We can't tell you which way is "best" unless you tell us what "best" means to you.  Note: don't respond with a tautology like "best practice."  *State your specific requirements.*

Comment: Edited my question to add more details to it. Sorry for posting it early.. Basically I need to send data to messaging queue in any of those three ways. As of now I can only send data by calling `sendToQueueAsync` method but wanted to see how can I extend my design so that I can send data in either of those three ways.

Comment: Why does the Packet class need to have knowledge about how it is being transmitted?

Comment: It doesn't need to I think. That was the design I was able to come up with. Is there any better way?

Comment: What do you mean by "better?"  I'm not trying to be difficult, I'm just trying to figure out what you want to achieve (other than writing three methods for sending a packet, a problem whose solution seems self-evident).

Comment: The way you asked your previous question, I thought you think I am doing something wrong and there was a better way in your mind so that's why I asked that question. I am not sure how to extend this design so that caller can send data in any way they want to. As of now my design can only send data through async only. That's what I want to achieve basically.

Comment: Aren't you going to provide the caller three methods?  `sendToQueueAsync` by passing two parameters,
`sendToQueueSync` by passing two parameters,
`sendToQueueAsync` by passing three parameters.  Doesn't that achieve your objectives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is the `SendRecord.getInstance()...` calls in `sendData()`. My recommendation is to abstract that out as a policy. A sketch of a minimal change approach follows.

Start by creating a `QueuePolicy` interface

```
public interface QueuePolicy {
    public boolean sendToQueue(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords);
}
```

Pass this to the `Packet` constructor `public Packet(final RecordPartition recordPartition, final QueuePolicy qPolicy)`, and store in an instance variable i.e. `this.qPolicy = qPolicy;`.

Replace the `SendRecord.getInstance()...` call in `sendData()` with

```
qPolicy.sendToQueue(address, buffer.array());
```

Now, in `validateAndSend(...)`, construct an object that implements the interface and pass that to the `Packet` constructor. If your client doesn't have access to `validateAndSend(...)` then you'll need to add a `QueuePolicy` parameter to `validateAndSend` and have the client pass it in.

An example class that implements the `QueuePolicy` is below. The other two variants should follow the same pattern (but without the `Socket` instance);

```
public class QPolicyAsyncWithSocket implements QueuePolicy {
    private final Socket socket;

    public QPolicyAsyncWithSocket (Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public boolean sendToQueue(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords) {
        return SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueSync(address, encodedRecords, socket);
    }
}
```

Comment: I liked your idea of passing the implementation of `QueuePolicy` interface to `Packet` constructor and then we can call directly `sendToQueue` method on that implementation. That makes sense. Now I am thinking more on this, I have three implementations of `QueuePolicy` and from all those implementations I am just calling corresponding method of `SendRecord` class. Right? So can we not get rid of "SendRecord" class altogether and have them implemented in these three implementations of `QueuePolicy` interface somehow by making sure all the logic of "SendRecord" class is there?

Comment: @user1950349 Possibly. It’s not clear from the context why SendRecord is a singleton. If the client will always pick one policy, that you’ll reuse, or it’s actually fine to have multiple queues then this should work ok. If not, or you’re not sure, it may be best to wrap the singleton.

Comment: Idea is - sometimes we have to send data through "async" and sometimes we can send data through "sync" so it's up to clients to decide how they wants to do it. That's why I was thinking to have a base abstract class kind of thing. I am trying to do it this way now but stuck as of now on the common implementations for them.

Comment: @user1950349 I understand but the SendRecord singleton looks like it was written to ensure that there’s only one thread and one cache. If you move away from that model, by moving the implementation to the QueuePolicy concrete classes, you’ve probably got some complex syncing problems. TBH the SendRecord class looks reasonably sensible. Unless you have a strong reason to remove it, I’d be inclined to leave it. Up to you of course.

Comment: I have a quick question on this. With your suggestion, I can pass queue policy implementation in the constructor of `Packet` class and then call that implementation to send data. So how can I know whether data was successfully sent or not? Because my methods in `Packet` class doesn't return a boolean and they are just void. For example: let's say `dataHolders` only has one element in it so when we call `close` method of packet class,  then only it will send data so do I need to evaluate boolean values both from `addAndSendJunked` and `close` method?

Comment: @user1950349 interesting question. I think it makes sense to have `sendData()` return `true` if the `itemBuffer` is empty otherwise return the result of `sendToQueue()`. If only to give your public API full visibility.  It's not so clear what your API should do. The reason is that those booleans don't really tell you much. If you get a `false` then you haven't sent something but you can't tell what or why. If you get a `true` then you may or may not have sent something. So a client can't really do much with the information other than log that something probably happened.

Comment: @user1950349 A cleaner option may be to have a `getStatus()` method on `SendRecord` that you can poll for outstanding messages, errors etc.  You could expose this via `QueuePolicy`. Obviously, this is a non-trivial change and would require more info about your messaging system to offer a sketch of a solution.

Comment: For those two sync policies I need to verify whether data was successfully sent or not so that's why it is important for me to know the status. For sync cases, I will definitely know whether data was sent or not because it's a sync call and both of those implementation will tell me from `sendToQueue` call whether it was successfully sent or not. I didn't quite understand your suggestion of `getStatus` method and exposing it via `QueuePolicy`. Can you provide an example here so that I can understand if possible?

Comment: Also what do you think of having a boolean field in class `Packet` and a getter to be able to get its value at any time? Do you think this is right here?

Comment: @user1950349 The problem you have, even with sync jobs, is that the client won't know what failed. About the only thing they can know is that it wasn't the argument to `addAndSendJunked` that caused the failure. It would be a very confusing API. I'll try and sketch out what I mean by `getStatus()` when I get some time. I'll  have to guess at some of the messaging API though.

Comment: In my case I am already logging with error messages if it fails under a certain condition so I am not worried about that why it failed as I can check the logs. Important thing is I want to know whether it was sent or not from that boolean flag.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [FutureTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) to simplify your interface.  A `FutureTask` instance is nothing more than a task that once run will return a result.  The `Executor` classes play well with them too, because they are just an extension of a `Runnable` class.

Your `SendRecord` class can therefore by simplified into `sendToQueue` method accepting two parameters and returning a `FutureTask`.  You then need only append to your `Executor` to manage the execution of these tasks in the manner of your choosing.  You can also chain future tasks together should the result of one be required by a successive future task should you wish it.

The task performed by `FutureTask` would then therefore be responsible for:

1. Performing sendoff of packet
2. Await response until timeout.
3. If response not received or if response is failure:

   - If retry count is zero, set result to failure.
   - Otherwise decrement retry count, and return to step 1.
4. Otherwise response received and success:

   - Set result to success.

To simply perform a synchronous call, you'd need only to call `get()` to force the task to resolve to success or failure, though ideally you should avoid forcing resolution of the task as long as possible, as it allows you to work in parallel for as long as possible.

In doing it this way, you have full flexibility and none of the clunky mixing of synchronous and asynchronous implementations, while still maintaining full control over when these tasks resolve.  The actual sending of the packet is also entirely kept within its own world making adjustments far more straightforward.  It would be easy to see how you could adapt a `FutureTask` instance to chain with other calls as well.

```
public class PacketChain extends FutureTask<PacketResponse> {
    private FutureTask<PacketResponse> task;
    private PacketChain next = null;

    public PacketChain(FutureTask<PacketResponse> task) {
        super(task, null);
        this.task = task;
    }

    public PacketChain add(FutureTask<PacketResponse> nextFutureTask) {
        next = new PacketChain(nextFutureTask);
        return next;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            PacketResponse response = task.get();

            set(response);

            if(next != null && ResponseStatus.OK.equals(response.getStatus())) {
                // Launch successive packet in same thread (synchronously) 
                set(next.get());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            // This will ensure interruption or other exceptions will bubble up
            setException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, you'd simply have to do the following to add successive tasks to the first packet:

```
PacketChain task = new PacketChain(firstPacketTask);
task.add(secondPacketTask)
    .add(thirdPacketTask);
```

Perhaps your `SendRecord` class could then focus on splitting the information into pieces and returning a single `PacketChain` representing the cumulation of all calls necessary to send the information required.

Answer (score -1):

Since you asked it here and not on stackexchange.
Maybe you went in a wrong design, should users need to decide if your program sends sync or async, your sure ?. Decisions like that should not be made by users, they should be idiot proven to work in all situations. your program should discover itself what's best, reducing the number of user interface options.